# For a reference month, how many customers did we lose and how many customers returned in reference month?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My final req is - I need to plot a Month-on-Month line graph of % of lost customers that are reactivated in Reference month.

So, for each Reference month (for example : March-2019), I need to see how many customers did I lose before March (last "Sale date" before Mar-2019 being 3 months older than March-2019, for example: Nov-2018,Oct-2018,Sep-2018,Aug-2018, July-2018...... ) and how many of *these* customers reactivated in Mar-2019 (have a "Sale date" in Mar-2019)

Can you please help with the code? I am novice to advanced SQL and have been stuck at this point for a long time.

```
Sample Expected Result : 

Sale_Month     Lost_customers                   Reactivated_customers
             (prev Sale date before             (Prev Sale date before 
              Sale_month  > 3 months)            Sale_month > 3 months and                      
                                                have a Sale date in given 
                                                 Sale month)

  Mar-19          1,050                            180
  Apr-19          900                              80           
  May-19          1,400                            160
  June-19         1,200                            110
  July-19         1,800                            130
  Aug-19          1,900                            140



Sample Data : 
Customer      Sale Date
AAAAA        11/17/2018
BBBBB        11/19/2018
CCCCC         9/22/2018
CCCCC         1/24/2019  
AAAAA         3/16/2019    ----> so for Reference month of March, AAAAA to 
CCCCC         3/18/2019          be considered in "Lost_customers" because 
                             AAAAA's previous sale date (11/15/2018) is
                             more than 3 months from the Ref month 
                            (March - 2019) and AAAAA to be considered in 
                             "Reactivated_customers" because AAAAA has a 
                             Sale date in the given month (March-2019) 


                         ----> for given month of March, CCCCC to not 
                             be considered in "Lost customers" and
                             "Reactivated customers" because 
                             previous sale date (1/25/2019) is less 
                             than 3 months from Ref month (March-2019)
                             and hence does not appear in 
                             "Reactivated_customers" as well
```

Comment: Using `Coman table expresion` you can achieve this.

Comment: @jishansiddique, could you please help me with the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your schema for better understanding?

Comment: @jishansiddique My table is a Sales fact table and has information similar to my Sample data but has additional "Sale price"column . So basically, Customer ID, Sale date and Sale Price are the columns

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated.  The challenge is counting customers in the months when they have no data.  One idea is to expand the data with one row per customer and month.  Then aggregate and use conditional aggregation:

```
select yyyymm.yyyymm,
       sum( (t.last_yyyymm < yyyymm.last_yyyymm - interval '3 month')::int ) as last_customers,
       sum( ((t.last_yyyymm < yyyymm.last_yyyymm - interval '3 month')::int ) and t.yyyymm is not null)::int ) as restarts
from (select distinct customer from t
     ) c cross join
     (select distinct date_trunc('month', saledate) as yyyymm
     ) yyyymm left join
     (select customer, date_trunc('month', saledate) as yyyymm,
             min(date_trunc('month', saledate)) over (partition by customer) as min_yyyymm,
             lag(date_trunc('month', saledate)) over (partition by customer order by min(saledate)) as last_yyyymm
      from t
      group by customer, date_trunc('month', saledate)
     ) t
     on t.customer = c.customer and t.yyyymm = yyyymm.yyyymm
group by yyyymm.yyyymm;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you very much for this code, I am running it in fragments and this seems to work. However, I wanted to understand, in *y.last_yyyymm* where is table alias *y* coming from? Please guide. Thanks once again!

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for updating the code. I am getting an error at  *yyyymm.last_yyyymm* in the outer most select statement, should this be *d.yyyymm* instead? Please guide. Thank you once again!